# Managers can only see items assigned to their teams

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, item-level-permissions

I'm new at Sharepoint development and the task I was given was to create an employee survey form where employees rate themselves and the work they do. Each person belong to a team that is assigned to a certain Manager. The manager will then view the survey form they have finished so they can document it.

My question is: How can I set this up where a manager can only see the items on the list that is assigned to his team? Other managers should not be able to view items from the other teams he's not assigned to. I've been looking for a solution everywhere and would really want to finish this as soon as possible. Thank you!

Follow Up: Should I use Workflow for this or is it just mainly focused on Group / User Permissions?

Comment: Are ok using designer customization

Comment: I have sharepoint designer as well on my office computer, maybe I can work around there as well

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have some kind of list of users and managers then when the item is created with workflow modify permission giving it to author and the manager only.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. So, I'm going to have one user per manager? Because the managers shouldn't be able to see the content of other managers.

Comment: You should create one SP sec group per Manager, Managers will come and leave and you will have to write a script to update older entries with Sec group you just add and remove Manager that changed (or a person who is seconding for him while he is on Leave.

Answer (score 0):

For above you need to add a question in your survey for populating managers(add question field with people and group, naming it as manager with fill the field with manager name by user or workflow).

And once you get manger

- Goto All response view.
- Edit the page.
- Edit the webpart property of
  the list view.
- click on the property change the current view.
- And in
  the filter view uncheck the "Show all items in this view" option
  Select the "Show items only when the following is true:".
- In Show the
  items when column select field Managers and equals to [Me].

click ok and save the page.
And if you are not ok with customizing the view let me know you can create a seperate view with designer and apply steps on it.

**As mention for security you can**

- create a worflow on survey list with impersonate step
- Add **Replace list item Permission** action
- Click on Choose button. And select Workflow lookup for user
- Datasource : current item
- Field from source : ManageName(added as question in survey)
- return as : string

And set workflow trigger on item added.

Comment: This is just hiding the answers this solution is not providing security trimming. User can navigate to the list and chose another view.

Comment: Yes, exactly its all about managing the permission.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses! I am actually looking on doing this as well, but like @MarekSarad said, it will only hide and will not provide security trimming. We need to make the entries private to other managers.

Comment: Update steps for security which will set item level permission with managers that are mention in the item.